# IIS 7 + ASP.NET 4

Tags: iis, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application that I am trying to convert to an ASP.NET 4 application. The application is fairly simple.  I have created a new web application in IIS 7.5 pointing to the directory that the ASP.NET application exists in.

When I attempt to execute the application, but entering http://localhost:[port] into my browser, I receive the following error:

> Error Summary
>   HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
>   Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> - Managed handler is used; however, ASP.NET is not installed or is not installed completely.
> - There is a typographical error in the configuration for the handler module list.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have the same problem when try publishing SL App using VS2010 although there is no prob before with .NET 3.5SP1 and VS2008.

So try run this (`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`) as described here [forums.iis.net/t/1149449.aspx](http://forums.iis.net/t/1149449.aspx) and here [www.gotknowhow.com/articles/fix-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-iis7](http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/fix-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-iis7) and It works now. So the problem is ASp>NET 4.0 has not properly installed, huuu... :)

Comment: works for me! I installed VS and IIS in the wrong order (VS first), then you end up in this situation

Answer (score 3):

the "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" trick worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to re-install the .NET 4 framework.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS Manager, under Sites, find your directory(Web Page) and Convert to Application. Select a valid Application Pool(or create a new one), which uses .NET v.2 or above. Restart IIS. You are done.

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check:

1) Did you install the .NET 4.0 bits on the box?

2) Is the site in question set to use ASP.NET 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amol/archive/2009/03/31/aspx-pages-not-getting-served-on-iis-7.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amol/archive/2009/03/31/aspx-pages-not-getting-served-on-iis-7.aspxBlockquote)

> Resolution: Add global modules section in applicationHost.config
>
> <add name="ManagedEngine" image="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\webengine.dll" 
>   preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
>
> for 64 bit
>   <add name="ManagedEngine64" image="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\webengine.dll" 
>   preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" />